# From ByteBuffer to object

Tags: java, bytebuffer, unsafe

I want to convert a `ByteBuffer` (coming from a network stream and consisting e.g. of `<double, double, bool, int>` in that order) to an object e.g. of the given class `AClass`:

```
class AClass {
    public double aDouble;
    public double anotherDouble;
    public boolean aBoolean;
    public int anInteger;
}
```

We can assume, that

- the size of each primitive datatype in the `ByteBuffer` is known and constant (e.g. 4 bytes for `double`, 1 byte for `boolean`).
- the order of the primitive datatypes in the `ByteBuffer` is always the same.

Is there an efficient (cast-like) way to convert the `ByteBuffer` to a given class object? Can I use some kind of a mask to mask the primitive data types?

```
mask:  | double  | double  |bool| ...
bytes: | - - - - | - - - - | -  | ...
```

Basically I am looking for something like [Matlab's `memmapfile`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memmapfile.html?refresh=true) function. Thanks alot.

Comment: No, write your own converter that pulls from the `ByteBuffer` and invokes some constructor or setter(s) from `AClass` with the corresponding values.

Comment: Also, nitpick, but usually `float` is 4 bytes or more, `double` is 8 or more.

Comment: This is an unusual case: It comes directly from some hardware (not a standard PC).

Comment: @MichaelDorner: Java `double` is _always_ 8 bytes; Java `float` is _always_ 4 bytes.  It is hardware-independent.

Comment: I refer to the ByteBuffer containing floats and doubles (byte values).

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with Unsafe. It supports copying of data directly between native memory and objects.  However in Java you have no control over the order of fields, nor how much padding is used. e.g. the `boolean` to can placed after the `int` to improve alignment and packing of the object, or padding can be added between fields.

You are better off copying the field one at a time.  While this might seem slower, in reality the main issue is bring the data into the L1 cache and the copy of each field is pretty quick by comparison.

Comment: What do you mean by _do this_? How do they get from `ByteBuffer` to `AClass` with `Unsafe`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis for your eyes only. on a 64-bit JVM you might do. `theUnsafe.copyMemory(null, ((DirectBuffer) byteBuffer).address(), object, 12, 16)` assuming you want to copy from the start of the ByteBuffer, 16 bytes and the header of the object is 12 bytes long. However, you wouldn't do this unless you knew the layout of the object e.g. a primitive array might be ok.

Comment: _I too like to live dangerously._ I looked over the methods of `Unsafe` with autocomplete on eclipse and I missed that one. Pretty sweet. Have to try it while I still can.

Answer (score 2):

The reasonably idiomatic and maintainable way to do something like this, available since Java 1.0, is with a DataInputStream...

```
void fillFromBytes(byte[] arr) throws IOException {
  DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(arr));
  aDouble = dis.readDouble();
  anotherDouble = dis.readDouble();
  aBoolean = ( dis.readByte() != 0 );
  ...
```

Since you're already working with a ByteBuffer (since 1.4), however, you have a range of methods directly on it such as [getDouble()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getDouble()). That gives you similar methods for reading primitive data from arbitrary offsets...

```
void fillFromBytes(ByteBuffer buf) throws IOException {
  aDouble = buf.getDouble();
  anotherDouble = buf.getDouble();
  aBoolean = ( buf.getByte() != 0 );
  ...
```

You can deal with padding by skipping to an absolute position after it, e.g.

```
 anotherDouble = buf.getDouble(0x24);
```

or by skipping over it a byte at a time:

```
 int npad = buf.getShort();
 for (int i=0 ; i < npad; i++) buf.getByte();
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine, but that's is far away from efficient: Every conversion is followed by two constructor calls.